# Why can't I use the standard CSS annotation using the '#' symbol to grab elements with IDs on Selenium Webdriver, using the @FindBy annotation?

Tags: selenium, css-selectors, webdriver

Given an element on a web page that has an id:

```
id="j_idt74:addNewTypeBtn"
```

I'm using the '@findBy' annotation way of grabbing web page elements.

Using:

```
@FindBy(how=How.CSS, using="input#j_idt74:addNewTypeBtn")
WebElement mAddButton;
```

Gives an error:
'The given selector input#j_idt74:addNewTypeBtn is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: An invalid or illegal selector was specified'

However if I use the ID as an attribute notation, such as:

```
@FindBy(how=How.CSS, using="input[id=\"j_idt74:addNewTypeBtn\"]")
WebElement mAddButton;
```

It works normally.

Why can't I use the standard CSS notation using the '#' symbol to grab elements with IDs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ID in your case contains a colon, which is a special character in CSS selectors (used to denote a pseudo-class or a pseudo-element). The selector is thus being treated as `input`, `#j_idt74` and `:addNewTypeBtn`, which is of course incorrect.

You can use an ID selector, but you need to escape the colon like so:

```
@FindBy(how=How.CSS, using="input#j_idt74\\:addNewTypeBtn")
WebElement mAddButton;
```

Comment: @Sam: Your developers might not be happy, but it'd be useful if they changed the element IDs, removing or replaceing colons so they can be compatible with CSS.